# Length of sentence and its effect on a possessor

Tags: grammar, possessives

Please consider the following sentence:

> When a function is about to call a subfunction, it puts the memory
>   address of the next instruction to execute upon returning from the
>   subfunction (**its** “return address”) at the top of the stack.

In my opinion, the possessor ("its", shown in bold) is too far away from the subject it is referring to (i.e. the "function" described in very first part of the language).

In English linguistics, does this problem have a special name? (I.e. When the sentence gets too long such that the reader is confused about relationships in the sentence.)

Also, I tried to rewrite the above sentence to make it more readable, but I could not, because there is a lengthy description (i.e. "the memory address of the next instruction to execute upon returning from the subfunction") that needs to be kept together and this makes restructuring attempts difficult.  Is the solution to split up the sentence into smaller sentences?

PS: Didn't know how to tag this question and decided on 'grammmar' as a catch-all.  Please feel free to re-tag.

Comment: you can avoid it with "*the* return address*"  Or rewrite to something like: "Before branching to a subroutine, the *return address* (the memory address of the next instruction to execute after the subroutine completes) is placed on the stack."

Comment: @Jim Brilliant (*the* instead of *its*) as well as the rewrite; thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the name for the phenomenon, but you're right, a reader can get lost or confused since the antecedent of *its* may not be clear.

You could move things around:

**When a function is about to call a subfunction, it puts at the top of the stack a "return address", that is, the memory address of the next instruction to be executed upon returning from the subfunction.**

Comment: +1 for teaching me about *antecedent*; I looked it up here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antecedent_%28grammar%29.